Using VBA code to move OLDEST emails in outlook inbox instead of newest
I have created a macro and attached it to a button in outlook. I want my CSRs to be able to press a button and receive any emails they should reply to and then be able to request additional emails to respond to. We do this by categorizing replies with the users name and moving them to a corresponding folder.
The macro should move over all already categorized emails and tell the person how many were moved and ask if they'd like additional. This is all working as expected, however, if the CSR requests additional emails I want it to pull the oldest non-categorized ones and it seems to be pulling the NEWEST emails instead. I have tried changing the sort from false to True with no luck. Any help is very much appreciated! I did try to change the names of the folders/inbox for anonymity.
Sub MoveAndCategorizeEmails()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMSREmails As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim movedCount As Integer
    Dim additionalEmails As Integer
    Dim userResponse As String
    Dim categoryName As String
    Dim additionalResponse As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Set the category name (customize this for each user)
    categoryName = "XXXXXX" ' Replace with your actual category name

    ' Get the namespace (MAPI) and the shared inbox folder
    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNamespace.Folders("CUSTOMERSERVICES").Folders("Inbox") ' Update this if the shared inbox name is different
    Set olMSREmails = olNamespace.Folders("CUSTOMERSERVICES").Folders("CSR Emails") ' Ensure this folder exists
    Set olItems = olInbox.Items

    ' Sort items by received date in ascending order (oldest first)
    olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    ' Initialize counters
    movedCount = 0

    ' Loop through the items in the inbox and move categorized emails
    For i = olItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeOf olItems(i) Is MailItem Then
            Set olMail = olItems(i)
            ' Check if the email is categorized with the specified name
            If olMail.Categories = categoryName Then
                ' Move the email to the corresponding folder
                Set olFolder = olMSREmails.Folders(categoryName) ' Ensure a folder with the category name exists under "MSR Emails"
                olMail.Move olFolder
                movedCount = movedCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Prompt the user for the number of additional emails to categorize and move
    additionalResponse = InputBox("A total of " & movedCount & " emails were moved to your folder. How many additional emails do you want to categorize and move?", "Additional Email Request")
    If Not IsNumeric(additionalResponse) Or additionalResponse <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid number."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    additionalEmails = CInt(additionalResponse)

    ' Categorize and move additional emails if needed
    If additionalEmails > 0 Then
        Dim additionalMovedCount As Integer
        additionalMovedCount = 0 ' Initialize counter for additional emails
        For i = 1 To olItems.Count ' Loop from oldest to newest
            If TypeOf olItems(i) Is MailItem Then
                Set olMail = olItems(i)
                ' Check if the email is not categorized
                If olMail.Categories = "" Then
                    ' Categorize the email with the specified name
                    olMail.Categories = categoryName
                    ' Move the email to the corresponding folder
                    Set olFolder = olMSREmails.Folders(categoryName) ' Ensure a folder with the category name exists under "MSR Emails"
                    olMail.Move olFolder
                    additionalMovedCount = additionalMovedCount + 1
                    ' Exit the loop if the maximum number of additional emails is reached
                    If additionalMovedCount >= additionalEmails Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    ' Send a summary email
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNewMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olNewMail
        .To = "XXXX@XXXXX.com"
        .Subject = "Email Move Summary"
        .Body = "I requested " & additionalEmails & " additional emails to be categorized and moved."
        .Send
    End With

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub


You might try refreshing and re-sorting olItems after the first loop, since you already removed some items from that collection.

added what I think would work and still no luck.
' Refresh the items collection
Set olItems = olInbox.Items
olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True


For i = 1 To olItems.Count you typically don't want to loop forwards over a collection if you're going to be removing items from it, so maybe reverse the sort and loop backwards as you do in your first loop.

worked with initial testing. Going to get an agent to try it and confirm.

@TimWilliams worked like a charm, thank you for the help!

Good to hear - added as an answer

You're using
For i = 1 To olItems.Count
but you typically don't want to loop forwards over a collection if you're going to be removing items from it, so maybe reverse the sort and loop backwards as you do in your first loop.
